# Configure Multiple Aws Accounts in Spinnaker's config

Tags: spinnaker

I want to configure two different AWS account credentials in Spinnaker. How can I add second account in spinnaker?

Thanks,
Puneet

Answer (score 1):

Here are the detailed instructions on how to add multiple accounts to Spinnaker as written by the Spinnaker development team. You basically need to add the ability to assume role from the secondary account - https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/tree/master/clouddriver-aws

Keep in mind that the default templates on spinnaker/spinnaker do not allow for multiple accounts and you have to edit clouddriver.yml directly to follow these instructions.